# How can I get MySQL database backup and restore it using Grails

Tags: mysql, grails

I want to take MySQL database backup and restore it in Grails. I am using Grails 2.1.1 . I have searched Google. Can I call a method of a controller and get backup of my database?

Comment: Do you want database backup programmatically or via command line??

Comment: @Abdullah I want it programmatically. Can you help please